# Unknown MySQL server host - connection problem

Tags: mysql

I am new to databases and I have been asked to look at a few tables and see how many records they have and some other information. I cannot access phpMyAdmin through cPanel, which is how I've always done it on my own server. I decided to download MySQL Workbench. I enter in all the information is asks: Hostname: mysite.startlogicmysql.com Port: 3306 Username: user. I press connect and get this

Unknown MySQL server host 'mysite.startlogicmysql.com' (11004)

Am I using the wrong hostname? I've seen a server name, a hostname in the server variables list which is something like custsql.eigbox.net and the server itself is custsql.eigbox.net
In both cases the custsql is a little different than what I posted. I am not sure which one to use. If there is anything else anyone needs to know I can tell you. Tanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's highly possible that the MySQL database is only available to the servers in the same infrastructure and that the name mysite.startlogicmysql.com is only a DNS entry available from inside.

I'm quite sure that whoever is managing your cPanel can provide more information about how to manage your MySQL database, otherwise you have some options as well.

- If you have SSH access try starting a ssh tunnel: `ssh -L3306:localhost:3306 user@host`
- If you can run PHP on your hosting install phpMyAdmin yourself

Answer (score 0):

Ok the default value for MySQL is that he listen only on his local IP.

This is configured in the my.cnf. If you have access to the configuration uncomment the line "bind-address 127.0.0.1" something like this. Restart the Server then you have access from outside. !!! BUT ITS NOT GOOD FOR SECURITY REASONS !!! All people from outside can access to the server. And Notice this is only possible for user that are configured with access from all hosts.

The easiest way is when you have phpmyadmin like lynxman says.